# Error with sending a sample stirng i.e "test". The android device will read the first letter then the rest of the string

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, sendmessage

I am using this sample code for my arduino uno with a bluetooth shield.  When I send data to my phone it receives the first character of the word read in from the serial port and then in a separate message it reads in the rest of the characters.
i.e
arduino sent: t
arduino sent: est

Very few times does it work correctly and even sometimes the output is incorrect

Could someone explain why this is occuring and how to fix it?

```
/*
BluetoothShield Demo Code Slave.pde. This sketch could be used with
Master.pde to establish connection between two Arduino. It can also
be used for one slave bluetooth connected by the device(PC/Smart Phone)
with bluetooth function.
2011 Copyright (c) Seeed Technology Inc.  All right reserved.

Author: Steve Chang

This demo code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
Lesser General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA

For more details about the product please check http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/

*/


/* Upload this sketch into Seeeduino and press reset*/

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   //Software Serial Port
#define RxD 6
#define TxD 7

#define DEBUG_ENABLED  1

SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
    pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
    setupBlueToothConnection();

}

void loop()
{
    char recvChar;
    while(1)
    {
        if(blueToothSerial.available())
        {//check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
            recvChar = blueToothSerial.read();
            Serial.print(recvChar);
        }
        if(Serial.available())
        {//check if there's any data sent from the local serial terminal, you can add the other applications here
            recvChar  = Serial.read();
            blueToothSerial.print(recvChar);
        }
    }
}

void setupBlueToothConnection()
{
    blueToothSerial.begin(38400);                           // Set BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n");             // set the bluetooth work in slave mode
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=SeeedBTSlave\r\n");    // set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave"
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n");             // Permit Paired device to connect me
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n");             // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
    delay(2000);                                            // This delay is required.
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n");                // make the slave bluetooth inquirable
    Serial.println("The slave bluetooth is inquirable!");
    delay(2000);                                            // This delay is required.
    blueToothSerial.flush();
}
```

Comment: Is some code missing?  Where is the Arduino code that sends the message "test" to your phone?

Comment: This is the complete code that is uploaded to the arduino uno.  The message test was an example of a word I type in to the serial port.

Comment: Try this:

while(Serial.available())
        {
            recvChar  = Serial.read();
            blueToothSerial.print(recvChar);
        }
blueToothSerial.flush();

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix the problem. Also by putting the flush method outside the while clause it does print out the value received by the arduino.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending data one character at a time `blueToothSerial.print(recvChar)` so the underlying bluetooth code will decide when to buffer and send.

Try sending the entire string at once `blueToothSerial.print("test");`

I find it useful to use println `blueToothSerial.println("test");` This way you can look for a a linefeed, "\n", when processing data on the phone.